# Delta function integration to find stress energy for a test particle

Tags: definite-integrals, dirac-delta, general-relativity

I am reading a paper, where the author considers the following integral:

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
T^{\mu \nu} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta^4 (x-z(\tau)) \frac{dz^{\mu}}{d \tau} \frac{dz^{\nu}}{d \tau} d\tau
\end{equation}

where $z^{\mu} = (T(\tau), R(\tau), \Theta(\tau), \Phi(\tau))$ and $\tau$ is the proper time. For context, it describes the stress energy tensor for a particle moving on a geodesic.

Now, they state the following simplification:

\begin{equation}
T^{\mu \nu} = \frac{dT}{d \tau} \frac{dz^{\mu}}{dt} \frac{dz^{\nu}}{dt} \frac{\delta(r-R(t))}{r^2} \delta^{(2)} (\Omega - \Omega(t))\tag{2}
\end{equation}

where $\Omega = (\theta, \phi) \text{ and } \delta^{(2)} (\Omega) = \delta(cos\theta)\delta(\phi)$.

I struggle to understand this simplification; I do not even see intuitively how $\frac{1}{r^{2}}$ and $cos\theta$ factors appear there. I would really appreciate some help in understanding this.

Answer (score 2):

1. They have integrated out $\tau$ by using $\delta(t-\tau)$;
2. They have used spherical coordinates, which leads to $\delta(r-R(t))/r^2$
3. The other components remain unchanged, thus you have $\delta(\cos(\theta))$ and $\delta(\phi)$.

The general delta function in 4D curved space is
$$
\frac{\delta^{4}(x-x_c)}{\sqrt{ |g| }}
$$
where $g$ is determinant of metric.

Delt function in spherical coordinates: Since $\sqrt{g}=r^2\sin\theta$, the full delta function without any additional symmetries should be
$$
\frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}
\delta( r- r_c) \delta( \theta- \theta_c)
\delta( \phi- \phi_c)
$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I can see that now. I am still slightly confused about the integration, in the first step you described, shouldn't it be $\delta(t-T(\tau))$? In that case how do we perform integration there, since $\tau$ is implicit there, i.e. given in a function?

Comment: Use a property of a delta function, $\delta(t-T(\tau))=\delta(t-\tau)/T'(\tau)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I should brush up on delta function properties